# How can I use Windows quick navigation combo keys under OSX?

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, word-processing

In any text area under Windows, you can use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>Right Arrow</kbd> to move from one word to the next. You can also add meta keys such as <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> or <kbd>DEL</kbd> to select words or delete them respectively.

How can I do this under OSX with minimal fuss?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use <kbd>ALT</kbd>-<kbd>Right Arrow</kbd> to move from word to the next. and <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>-<kbd>ALT</kbd>-<kbd>Right Arrow</kbd> to select the next word.

Answer (score 1):

You can use <kbd>FN</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> to delete

Answer (score 0):

Yes, what quentin said. On some mac keyboards <kbd>alt</kbd> is labelled <kbd>option</kbd>.

On the windows keyboard currently connected to my MacBook Pro, the key labelled "alt" is command and the windows key is used for alt/option.